# Laravel Eloquent latest item from 1-many table group by child table column

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8, mysql-8.0

I am using Laravel 8 with Mysql 8 *strict=true* sql mode.
I have 2 tables as under:

```
exam_results
    id, result_date

examresult_revisions
   id, examresult_id, result_part_id, revision_id, created_at, updated_at ...
```

Here are models relations

```
class Examresult extends Model
{
    public function revisions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ExamresultRevision::class);
    }
}
```

In words we may say that each exam result comes in different parts, result_part_id=1, result_part_id=2 and so on and each part may have one or more revisions.

I want to get latest ExamresultRevision record for each ExamResult group by result_part_id.

How can I achieve this??